# How to set Conditional type for one parameter with literal type of another parameter of the function

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

There is a simple function that select something by name or index

```
async function(value:number|string, by: 'index'|'name' = 'index'){
 switch(by){
  case 'index':{
    selectby(value)
  };
  case 'name':{
    selectby(value)
  } 
 }
}
```

is there a way to tell value type number if by is 'index' or not passed , else string

I have tried with function overloading:

```
 async function(value:number, by?: 'index' = 'index')
 async function(value:string, by: 'name' = 'index')
 async function(value:number|string, by: 'index'|'name' = 'index')
```

the problem is that , the implementation where  async function(value:number|string, by: 'index'|'name' = 'index') doesn't shows up on hovering the function. It shows the first override as the default function

How can i give a typescript documentation that if 'if index then number' else string

Answer (score 1):

What about using `typeof`? Then you don't need the `by` parameter at all:

```
switch(typeof value) {
    case "number": {
        selectBy(value)
    }
    case "string": {
        selectBy(value)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can compose your parameters as a custom object type, incorporating your stated constrains. This way, you will be forced to pass the right `by` for the `value` type. However, this will lead to only one parameter passed to your function:

```
type Value1 = { value: number, by: 'index' } | { value: string, by: 'name' }
const getValue1 = async function ({ value, by }: Value1) {
    switch (by) {
        case 'index': {
            selectby(value)
        };
        case 'name': {
            selectby(value)
        }
    }
}

getValue1({ value: 1, by: 'index' })
```

The same is possible for an array type:

```
type Value2 = [number, 'index'] | [string, 'name']
const getValue2 = async function ([value, by]: Value2) {
    switch (by) {
        case 'index': {
            selectby(value)
        };
        case 'name': {
            selectby(value)
        }
    }
}

getValue2([ 1, 'index' ])
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmAbewoCMCeMC8MAUAHgFxxQBOAlmAOYwA%20MYArgLZrxkCUOAfDAQCghUDAAd4MAGoBDRE3gBGHDADeMAG6z5JZmw4AaGJhIByKgBN4BEzAC%209VRq3wS0SjUPGYJsNJbwbWwFQSFhqeCgZOUVlaQgMMGAYADMmRKgKcHw1TWjPLFsSKPkFbhUBGEq4AHcKKGAAC3xMMoqq9uA4iTMwS2sScvahqoRkVEw8XPlONuHbAG5Zoc6Eb19-EwGl4crRlHQMSecZnbsloKDhMQli%20AAmZQBtXXYyQx6%20kwBdB0e3Kmo73WAS%20wXA0Bg4UizgeuDiCSSqXSmTA%20EeU3g%20S%20RRhrXaEFq9SaeBaqm2VRW3QsVk2ZNO%20KQ%20wmGJOOwW5MqlLWfgCW3pI0Z40OLI5Z3aFyEAihtwUeByzhICnypmp1jsM2lMLwjxgSu8qpsX04QA)

---

edit: Hovering and typing hints depend on your used IDE. Normally, you can switch the displayed signature using some arrow buttons at the sides:

[image: there are arrows to the left to show other overloads]

I am not aware of any mechanism to tell the IDE in which order to display the overloads.

Answer (score 1):

Your async example works just fine:

```
async function test(value:number, by: 'index'): Promise<void>;
async function test(value:string, by: 'name'): Promise<void>;
async function test(value:number|string, by: 'index'|'name' = 'index'): Promise<void> {
 }

test('test', 'name') // works
test(1, 'name') // does not work
test(1, 'index') // works
test('aa', 'name') // does not work
```

Your IDE will suggest the first function overload type by default, but as soon as you add a string as the first parameter, it should then suggest the user to add `name` as the second parameter.
[image]

You can find the playground example in the following [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQQwzgngdgxsBmBXWAXAlgeysFBTMKAFAG4gA2iuAXFIgLYBGuATgDTAMRXADkaUAE1wAPHgEpuABWYY6aMLgA8xDGgEA%20ANwAoUJFgJkMdFhz4ipCtQLN%20Ac3aduPKCDq5xUmXIXLVGnT1oOCRUTGw8AhJyShp6JmYAHxt7Ry5efiFRRJc3D2AAXgzBEU9gaVl5JRU1dWAAb10AX21tSKIedp52XPdxNvNCAEYezNKxIA).

Comment: hi i want the documentation to show it supports by name and index , here it shows only name

Comment: You mean in the declaration file (```.d.ts```)?

Comment: i dont have an explicit decalration file ,

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by **documentation**?

Comment: the documentation u get while hovering , see in the screenshot u added , it say value string and by: name , If it could show that by supports both name and index or show all the overrides , it would be great., I am using vscode

Comment: Unfortunately VSCode doesn't offer an auto-expanded mode for the intellisense suggestion box and it is something that is controlled internally by the IDE.
You can find all the other available settings here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense